# QPushButton multiple lines of text formating

Tags: qt

I have a button and on that button I have two lines of text.

```
QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton(...);
QString normal = "normal";
QString bold = "bold";
btn->setStyleSheet("text-align: right;");
btn->setText(normal + '\n' + bold);
```

I want to make the `normal` font-size to be `18`. I also want to make the `bold` font-weight to be `bold` and font-size should be `24`.

I know that I could use `setstylesheet`, but the button have two lines of code and I have no idea how could I separate them via `setstylesheet`.

Comment: the easiest way that may help you  is to use picture and `btn->setIcon("path");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this way, I create a label and set its parent pushbutton

```
    QString     normal = "normal";
    QString     bold   = "bold";
    auto const  text   = QStringLiteral("<font size=18>%1</font><br><b><font size=24>%2</font></b>")
                         .arg(normal.toHtmlEscaped())
                         .arg(bold.toHtmlEscaped());
    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton(this);
    btn->setGeometry(QRect(70, 30, 150, 100));
    QLabel *lbl = new QLabel(btn);
    lbl->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 150, 100));

    lbl->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
    lbl->setText(text);
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: That looks almost good, need to insert `<br>` to `QStringLiteral` cuz I need a line break inside the string. But how could I align the text to the right. I cannot find a way to do that. I have tried set  `lbl->setStyleSheet("qproperty-alignment: right;");` but does not solve it.

Comment: @taiwan12 you should style label. `lbl->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);` label has setAlignment function

Comment: Using `.arg(normal.toHtmlEscaped(), bold.toHtmlEscaped())` makes less heap allocation, so it even better than using chain `arg`